# Hibernate Query Using Criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

i'm newbie in Hibernate. I have to implement this query

```
SELECT A.num1a B.num1b,
   A.num2a B.num2b FROM A inner join B on A.ida = B.idb WHERE A.ida > 10;
```

with Criteria but i have no idea. Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, though not tested, but atleast you can start with this.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
c.createAlias("a.B", "b"); // inner join by default
c.add(Restrictions.gt("a.ida", 10));
return c.list();
```

[Restrictions](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.8.Final/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.java#Restrictions.le%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

[Criteria](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.8.Final/org/hibernate/Criteria.java?av=f)